# TypeError: JSDOM is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I'm trying to run the getting started code for JSDOM

```
const JSDOM = require("JSDOM");


const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent);
```

However, I receive this error message:

```
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
            ^

TypeError: JSDOM is not a constructor
```

I'm running on version "17.7.1" of node.js

Comment: `const {JSDOM} = require("JSDOM");`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exact problem on jsdom and found the solution on [this thread](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/942#issuecomment-314715229).

There may be a problem with the given version of jsdom, so i downgraded mine to jsdom@11.1.0 (coming from 21.1.0) as the author referenced.

Run the command `npm i jsdom@11.1.0 --save` and it should be fine. This is not a permanent resolution and in the future it might be useful to change to other library.

Don't forget to commit and push the package.json changes.